# Jenkins pipeline script - change git branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to get the name of a git branch, but the following code doesn't return the expected output.

```
def getbranches = ("git ls-remote -h https://github.com/my_repo").execute().getText()

print getbranches.readLines()
.collect { it.split()[1].replaceAll("refs/heads/", "")  }
.unique()
.findAll { it.startsWith('r') }
```

It should return something like: *release/1.1* but it outputs *false*.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
git url: 'https://github.com/my_repo', branch: 'master'

def getBranch = bat (returnStdout : true, script: "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login -c \"git branch -a | grep remotes/origin/release/[^/]*\$ | cut -d / -f 4\"")
String[] getReleaseVersion = getBranch.split('\n')
```